# Returning an instance of abstract class from java method

Tags: java, json, switch-statement, abstract-class, json-deserialization

I have a method that needs to return an object of abstract class type 'Transaction'. The classes 'PremiumTransaction' and 'NonPremiumTransaction' both extend 'Transaction'. The code attached here throws 'missing return statement' error. And I am not sure what to return in this method.

```
private Transaction myMethod( String jsonString ,String transactionType){

 switch(transactionType){
    case "PREMIUM":
      return mapper.readValue(jsonString, PremiumTransaction.class);
    case "NON-PREMIUM":
      return mapper.readValue(jsonString, NonPremiumTransaction.class);
    case "UNKNOWN":
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to parse JSON string : " + json String);

 }

}
```

I tried initializing an object of type 'Transaction' like

```
Transaction transaction = null;
```

and assigning the deserialized object inside the switch cases like

```
transaction = mapper.readValue(jsonString , PremiumTransaction.class);
```

But I don't want to return a null object if the argument for transaction type == "UNKNOWN"

Comment: what do you want to return  when you are given a transaction type of "UNKNOWN"? Also you should have a default for your switch case. Both should do the same thing. Nothing wrong with NULL if you aren't given a valid transaction type.

Comment: Adding a `default` case will remove the error. I personally would throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, just like you did within the `UNKNOWN` case.

Comment: Your problem is that you're missing the `default` case.  Just replace `case "UNKNOWN":` with `default:` and your code will compile.

Comment: You have at least two good options here. Return an optional,  or implement a new class of type Transaction, known as null object pattern. Google for ir I think that Will suit you nucely.

Comment: @MCEmperor , Dawood ibn Kareem ... Adding the default case resolved the error. Thank you!